# Bootstrap Navbar non collapse (prevent)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make a navbar using bootstrap to my own needs, but have stumbled upon a problem.

I want the first two links from the left (home and menu glyphicons) to not collapse when window is sized down. The rest would collapse.

Screenshot link
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQlN1.jpg)

Here is my code

```
<template name="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="navbar-nav" href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>  
          <li><a class="navbar-nav" id="showMenu" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span></a></li>  
        </ul>
      </div>




      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="{{activeRouteClass 'home' 'newPosts'}}">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'newPosts'}}">New</a>
          </li>
          <li class="{{activeRouteClass  'bestPosts'}}">
            <a href="{{pathFor 'bestPosts'}}">Best</a>
          </li>

          {{#if currentUser}}
            <li class="{{activeRouteClass 'postSubmit'}}">
              <a href="{{pathFor 'postSubmit'}}">Submit Post</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              {{> notifications}}
            </li>
          {{/if}}
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         {{> loginButtons}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move them into a separate `<ul>` object without the `nav navbar-nav` classes in order to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. The only problem is, with this solution, the two icons will not present themselves next to each other but in separate rows. Here is a screenshot. http://imgur.com/X2ExRmc